# Astropy/SkyCoord: How do I get the x-axis to show full degree range instead of negative numbers for angles > 180?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, astropy

I have the following code to plot several pairs of galactic coordinates, but would like for the x-axis to show the full degree range instead of negative numbers for angles greater than 180. Suggestions? Am I just overlooking a SkyCoord parameter?

Working example:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [8,8] # [width, height]

df = pd.read_csv('sight_lines_coord.txt', delimiter='\s+', usecols=['l', 'b'])
stars = SkyCoord(df['l'], df['b'], frame='galactic', unit=u.deg)
plt.scatter(stars.l.wrap_at('180d'), stars.b)
plt.grid(True)
```

This is how my plot looks.
[image]

The data frame consists of two columns: longitude, latitude (ex. 325.0, -5.2)

I should have added this earlier, my apologies. If I use wrap_at('360d') I get this plot, which is not what I want.

[image]

Wrapping at 180 gives me the picture I want, I just need my xtick labels to be non-negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyplot.xticks` is the function for this. Called with no arguments, it returns a tuple, `(ticks, labels)`. `ticks` is the x coordinate of all current x-axis ticks, and `labels` is what they are labeled with. If called with two arguments, it sets the tick values.

There's one caveat, which is that sometimes the `labels` you get from pyplot.xticks() are empty until after you call plt.show() (I'm not exactly sure why). That means you should only use `ticks` to set the labels.

```
plt.figure()
x = np.arange(-30, 30, 1)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x/10))
ticks, labels = plt.xticks()

for tick, label in zip(ticks, labels):
    tick_value = tick if (tick >= 0) else tick + 360
    label.set_text(str(tick_value))
    
plt.xticks(ticks, labels)
```

[image: Plot generated by the above code, ticks ranging from 320 to 350, then jumping to 0 up to 40]

---

Inverting the X-axis would look something like:

```
lower, upper = plt.xlim()
plt.xlim(upper, lower)
```

Again, called with no arguments, it returnsthe left boundary, then the right boundary. Called with two arguments, it sets the left and right boundaries. By flipping them, we can invert the axes. Incorporating that into the code above gives me:

[image: The same plot as the above, but the x axis has been inverted]

---

OLD ANSWER:

You use `Angle.wrap_at` [(docs here)](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.Angle.html#astropy.coordinates.Angle.wrap_at) which I think is the root of your problem.

`stars.l.wrap_at('180d')` will coerce all angles in your array to be within -180 <= angle < 180. For your case, you want the array to be wrapped such that 0 <= angle < 360, which would be accomplished by `stars.l.wrap_at('360d')`.

Comment: I tried that, but the plot displayed is completely different from what I want. I'll add what it does to my post. I want it to look like 30 to -30, but be labeled 30, 20, 10, 0, 350, 340, 330, etc.

Comment: Ohh! I misunderstood. My apologies. Give me a second to edit the post, that makes sense.

Comment: @bigswampmonster I edited an answer. Hopefully this helps more!

Comment: Thanks Keon! This totally worked! Out of curiosity, is it possible to invert the axis using the xticks function? Say, have it display from 40 to 320?

Comment: @bigswampmonster Depends on what you're trying to do. If you want the datapoints for higher x values to appear on the left, use plt.xlim(). I edited the answer. If you want to display the points in the same positions but convert +10 degrees to 350 degrees, then yeah, modifying the xticks should work.

Comment: Keon, you are awesome. That worked like a charm. And thanks for the explanations. I still really struggle with the logic for setting axis parameters, so this really helped. Marking this as an answer. Thanks again.